# Button Event Not Firing in WebControl

Tags: c#, asp.net-4.0

I'm attempting to create a "server control" that derives from WebControl.  This needs to be done entirely in C# so that it can be compiled into a .dll. I am not interested in creating a user control with a .ascx file (I actually already have a "user control" but I want to add it to a library so I'm converting it).

My control is dead simple right now and I can't get a button event to fire:

```
public class ButtonWrapper : WebControl
{
    protected Button button;

    public event EventHandler<Events.GenericEventArgs<Tuple<int, string>>> ButtonClicked;

    public void Button_Click(object o, EventArgs e)
    {
       ButtonClicked(this, new Tuple<int,string)(0, "abc"));
    }

    public void WHERE_DO_I_PUT_THIS_CODE()
    {
        button = new Button()
        {
          ID = "button",
          Text = "Button"
        };
        button.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);
    }
}
```

Where do I need to "create" the button?  I currently have it in an overloaded CreateChildControls():

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
{
    this.Controls.Clear();

    button = new Button()
    {
          ID = "button",
          Text = "Button"
    };
    button.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Click);

    this.Controls.Add(button);
    this.ChildControlsCreated = true;
 }
```

The control loads just fine, but when I click on the button, the page just refreshes and the event is never fired.  I want to the button in ButtonWrapper to fire so that the parent page can listen.  I think I'm close but I'm missing something simple.

Edit: I don't quite have the right event variables types for EventArgs passing and such when I was simplifying the problem for this question.

Comment: I hope this article can help u; http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/57280/WebControl-s-events-not-working-How-to-make-a-simp

Comment: That looks like exactly what I'm doing, but I can't get it to work.  I'll give it a try with the exact same code to rule out the possibility of VS being stupid or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created new solution and i tried it.
You can download from this link : http://dosya.co/download.php?id=51BACA121
I m at work and most of upload sites blocked. So i couldnt upload another site. If u cant download i can try find different upload site.

Comment: Your example worked and I basically just went through and compared that code to my code. The key difference was INamingContainer. If I add INamingContainer to the definition of "ButtonWrapper" I get the postback, if I remove it it doesn't work.  I have no idea why this affects anything. It looks like INamingContainer is just a "marker" interface but I don't know where its used. Thanks for your help.